# React-Native: Display/Render multiple images with snapshot.val()

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to load multiple images in my react-native-app feed page. I have stored it in my database and am able to retrieve the data using snapshot.val(), however, I don't understand how to actually display/render it on the feed screen.

When I do `console.log("CONSOLE.LOG --> Snapshot is: ", snapshot.val())`, this is what I get

```
CONSOLE.LOG --> Snapshot is:  Object {
  "4aae-47bb-e0f7-36e2-7e66": Object {
    "author": "edm9AAbPpFUWrO9HDXfV442QzSE2",
    "caption": "Test 1",
    "photo": Object {
      "2e30-b971-5c62-0b68-837f": Object {
        "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...someURL...",
      },
      "38de-15f2-bb7b-b58d-e863": Object {
        "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...someURL...",
      },
      "94f2-1494-908f-c17a-5adc": Object {
        "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...someURL...",
      },
    },
    "posted": 1562901067,
    "vote": 1,
  },
}
```

I am able to render "author", "caption", "posted", and "vote" by using a Flatlist like so:

```
          <FlatList
            refreshing={this.state.refresh}
            onRefresh={this.loadNew}
            data={this.state.photo_feed}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
              <View key={index}>
                <View>
                  <Text>{item.posted}</Text>
                  <Text>{item.author}</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <Image
                      source={{ uri: item.photo }}
                    />
                </View>
                <View>
                  <Text>{item.caption}</Text>
                    <View>
                      <View>
                        <Text>Votes: {item.vote}</Text>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
          />
```

but I don't understand how I can loop through the 3 "url" in "photo"

```
                <View>
                    <Image
                      source={{ uri: item.photo }}
                    />
                </View>
```

^ doesn't load any image

[image: If you want to see my database structure, it is explained in the image here. (I am using Google Firebase)]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop over the `photo` object's values and create `Image` component for each of the *photoItem* inside. Something like this might work,

```
<View>
{
  Object.values(item.photo).map(photoItem => (
    <Image source={{ uri: photoItem.url }} />
  )) 
}
</View>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, your answer makes sense. However, I keep getting this error when I implement your solution: TypeError: Object.values requires that input parameter not be null or undefined.

Is it because item.photo is a folder? How could I make it so I can refer to the "Photo unique ID" (as shown in the image above)? Thanks!

Comment: So basically, I would need to iterate through nested objects like so:

```
Object1 {
     Object2 {
           propertyIWantToAcess:
           anotherpropertyIWantToAcess:
      }
}
```

Comment: Like mentioned, the code above will loop through all photo url values and render multiple `Image` components. If you are looking to access photo unique id keys instead of `url` values then you can loop through the keys with `Object.keys(item.photo)` instead and get those.